# if i use an SSL certificate for my iOS or Android app to communicate with my server, can use any CA

Tags: ssl, certificate

If I use SSL for my app to communicate with my server, can I use any SSL certificate, like those issued by goDaddy? I understand the reason people buy Verisign certificates(which are terribly expensive) is that they are supported by all browsers. But if I have no browser component, and the communication is between my app and my services, can I go for a cheaper one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How SSL works

The Goal of SSL Certificates is to ensure no Man In the Middle is earsdropping on your encrypted communication. When your app is connecting to your server, your server therefore presents a certificate which tells, that the used encryption key really belongs to your server. This certificate is cryptographicly signed by a trusted party, such that the man in the middle can not forge such a certiifcate. Your app has to know the cryptographic key of the trusted party in advance to verify this signature.

## Use godaddy certificates

You can use any certificate made by a trusted party which is known by your app. If you include the godaddy cryptographic key (called root certificate) in your app you can use godaddy certificates.

## Use your own zero cost certificate

For you and your app, you yourself can be a trusted party for certificate signing. You can use your own self generated certificate without paying anyone for it. You only need to include your own certificate in your app. You can find a tutorial on how to generate a self signed certificate at http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html .